# I need: "when textBox1.Length = 4 in 1 index element add " " by insert"

Tags: c#

My code :

```
int len = textBox1.Text.Length;

if (len == 4)
{
   int one = 1;
   string empty = " ";
   textBox1.Text.Insert(one, empty);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you can't modify them you just create a new one. So you need to assign the result of `Insert` back to the `Text` Property:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(one, empty);
```